# I want to add user input object of an array with react useState(), when I send it it does not update the questions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, user-input, use-state

I have an object that has quizzes which is an array of objects. I would like the user to enter questions, correct_answer and incorrect_answers and send it to my database but its not doing it, it is sending it empty. I am having trouble with the onInputChange function to make my inputs go through

```js
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState({

    quizes:[{

      question : '',
      correct_answer: '',
      incorrect_answers:[]


    }]

  });


  useEffect(() => {
    loadQuestions(id);
  }, []);

  const loadQuestions = async ( id ) => {
    const result = await api.get(`/assignments/${id}`);
    setQuestions(result.data);
    
  };
 
  // const {quizes,question, correct_answer} = questions
  
  const onInputChange = e => {
    const value = e.target.value

    setQuestions({...questions, [e.target.name]: value });
  };

 
  // const addQuestion = async (id) => {
  //   await api.post(`/assignments/addquestion/${id}`);
  //   loadQuestions();
  // };
  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await api.post(`/assignments/addquestion/${id}`, questions);
  
    history.push("/dashboard");
    
  };
  

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {/* {console.log('this is the name of the question ** '+ questions.quizes.map(x=>x.question))} */}
      <div className="py-4">
        
        <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
        {/* {questions.quizes.map(x=>{ */}
            <div className="form-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control form-control-lg"
              placeholder="Enter question"
              name= {questions.quizes.question}
              value = {questions.quizes.question} 
              onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
            />
          </div>
        
          
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control form-control-lg"
              placeholder="Enter question"
              name='correct_answer'
              value={
                questions.quizes.correct_answer
              }
              onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
            />
          </div>
```

This is the output, it leaves the quizzes part empty

```
 {
        "createdAt": "2021-01-13T02:54:39.710Z",
        "_id": "5fff630624f06bfd45f6bcd2",
        "title": "testing this hhs",
        "quizes": [
            {
                "incorrect_answers": [],
                "_id": "5fff630d24f06bfd45f6bcd3",
                "question": "",
                "correct_answer": ""
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Comment: `questions.quizes.correct_answer` cannot be a valid input value because `quizes` is an array

Comment: I think that there's a problem between the declaration (quizes is an array) and the way you use it in the component, like an object. Try to solve this problem first

Comment: i tried using the maps function but it still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find here an example of something similar to what you're trying to achieve.

https://codesandbox.io/s/array-form-example-fg2yr?file=/src/App.js

Don't forget to split your code in multiple components. You can also use [react-fiinal-form](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form) to better manage your forms, with [react-final-form-arrays](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form-arrays) in your case